# Translate words from one database with other database translation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv, select

I have two databases, one database containing all my pictures like:

```
Database 1 name: images
-----+----------------------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+------------
| id | description                | tags                 | imagename | resolution | location  |
-----+----------------------------+----------------------+-----------+------------+------------
| 1  | We standing at eiffeltower | france, green, blue  | IMG01.JPG | 1280x1024  | /img/2020 |
| 2  | We standing at bridge      | france, orange, grey | IMG02.JPG | 1280x1024  | /img/2020 |
```

```
Database 2 name tagTranslations (for Dutch translation)
-----+--------+-----------------------
| id | tag    | translation          |
-----+--------+-----------------------
| 1  | france | frankrijk            |
| 2  | orange | oranje.              |
| 3  | grey   | grijs.               |
| 4  | green  | groen                |
| 5  | blue   | blauw                |
```

Now i want with 1 mysql query to get a result like this:
*"We standing at eiffeltower", "france, green, blue", "IMG01.JPG", "1280x1024", "/img/2020", "frankrijk", "groen", "blauw"*

*"We standing at bridge", "france, orange, grey", "IMG02.JPG", "1280x1024", "/img/2020", "frankrijk", "oranje", "grijs"*

Comment: will `tags` column always have three tags in it?

Comment: No, some have 3 tags, some have 10 tags or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first effort should go into fixing your data modeL Each image tag should be stored in a separate table, on a different row. Storing delimited lists in database columns in the root of many evils, as you are starting to see. More about this can be read in [this famous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).

That said, you could use a corelated subquery with `find_in_set()` and `group_concat()`:

```
 select
    i.id,
    i.description,
    (
        select group_concat(
            tt.translation 
            order by find_in_set(tt.tag, replace(i.tags, ', ', ','))
            separator ', ' 
        )
        from tagTranslations tt
        where find_in_set(tt.tag, replace(i.tags, ', ', ','))
    ) tags,
    i.imagename,
    i.resolution,
    i.location
from images i
```

The correlated subquery retrieves rows from the translation table whose `tag` can be found in the `tags` list of the corresponding `images` row. For this, we use handly MySQL function `find_in_set()` (we need to remove the space after the comma for the function to work properly); then, aggregation function `group_concat()` regenerates a delimited list of translations, using `find_in_set()` again to honor the original order of tags.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cc6cf92ff16191b8428a677b8482b93)**:

```
id | description                | tags                     | imagename | resolution | location 
-: | :------------------------- | :----------------------- | :-------- | :--------- | :--------
 1 | We standing at eiffeltower | frankrijk, groen, blauw  | IMG01.JPG | 1280x1024  | /img/2020
 2 | We standing at bridge      | frankrijk, oranje, grijs | IMG02.JPG | 1280x1024  | /img/2020
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for, and yes you are right. The data model is something i should work on. I haven't done this before because the first database is a pretty old one and the translation came later to my mind to get this implemented. Thanks a lot. Kudo's for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try out the code below:

```
CREATE VIEW table_comb AS
   SELECT * FROM images
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM tagTranslations
```